# operator overloading, using char

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to make stock management program, using operator overload

for example, if one tissue is sold, I want to operate using ' tissue-=1'

I made an array for products inventory P = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} each for tissue, calendar, fan, book, pen

part of my code(for test) is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class A{
   public:
      static int p[];
      int operator-(string &a){
         if (strcmp(a, "tissue")==0)
            return p[0]-=1;
         else
            cout<<"error"<<endl;
      }

};

int A::p[]={1,2,3,4,5}

int main(){
   A AA;
   "tissue"-=1;
   return 0;
}
```

I tried my best as beginner.. I know the codes are very wierd, please tell me anything I missed

Comment: You said *I want to make stock management program, using operator overload* Which one is more important?

Comment: You miss the very beginning - read a book (sorry, your code is junk)

Comment: You are missing the fundamental concept of what a class is. Instead of "class A" try thinking of it as "class product", then defining that class such that it containes everything you need to define a product in your homework. Basically a name, quantity. Apply the operator overloading to that class. Sorry I can't be specific, but when you are obviously missing an understanding of core concepts there really isn't a quick answer as to what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well, you want:

- AA be a container of objects:  `p[0]` would hold the quantity of "tissue", `p[1]` the quantity of "calendar", etc...
- to implement an operator that would decrease the quantity of an object in this container, by using its name.

## About solving your current issue:

Unfortunately your operator overload `int operator-(string &a)` is something that could substract a string value from an `A` and return an `int`.

So in `main()` you should write:

```
AA - "tissue";
```

## Improving slightly your approach:

The fact of having a side effect for `operator-` is very weird.  When you write x-1, you don't expect that x is changed, do you ?  I'd therefore suggest to improve the readability of your code by using an operator where a side effect is expected.

By the way, I'd also use strings like C++ strings, and not like c-strings.

```
  A& operator-= (string &a) {
     if (a == "tissue")
        p[0]-=1;    // p[0]-- would be an alternative as well ;-)
     else if (a=="calendar") 
        p[1]-=1; 
     //etc... 
     else
        cout<<"error"<<endl;
     return *this; 
  }
```

I suppose that your question is only about learning how to use operator overload, and not for wirting production quality code.  In this case this approach is fine.

## One step further:

In fact what you try to achieve in your own way, is a kind of associative container.  Forunately, this already exists in standard C++ with **[`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)**

All your code could be replaced with:

```
map<string, int> AA; 
AA["tissue"]++; 
AA["calendar"]+=10; 
AA["fan"] = AA["calendar"]*2;
cout << "I have "<<AA["tissue"] <<" tissues in stock"<<endl;
```

Comment: Thank you so much~ Great help!!